# Remove Pointer Attribute

Tags: c++, objective-c++

I have:

```cpp
template<typename T>
struct is_objective_c_type {
private:
  // Removes all pointer indirection.
  // object*** => object
  // object**  => object
  // object*   => object

  template<class U> struct remove_pointer                    {typedef U type;};
  template<class U> struct remove_pointer<U*>                {typedef typename remove_pointer<U>::type type;};
  template<class U> struct remove_pointer<U* const>          {typedef typename remove_pointer<U>::type type;};
  template<class U> struct remove_pointer<U* volatile>       {typedef typename remove_pointer<U>::type type;};
  template<class U> struct remove_pointer<U* const volatile> {typedef typename remove_pointer<U>::type type;};
  
public:
  static const bool value = std::is_base_of<NSObject, typename remove_pointer<T>::type>::value;
};
```

and currently it works like:

```cpp
@interface Foo: NSObject
@end

@implementation Foo
@end

is_objective_c_type<Foo>;  // true
is_objective_c_type<Foo*>;  // true
is_objective_c_type<Foo* __weak>; // false
is_objective_c_type<Foo* const*>;  // true
```

As you can see, it fails if I add the `__weak` attribute.
However, if I change the template of `remove_pointer` to:

```cpp
template<class U> 
struct remove_pointer<U* __weak>
{
    typedef typename remove_pointer<U>::type type;
};
```

It'll work. But that means it will never work for `Foo*` because it is implicitly `__unsafe_unretained` and it also won't work for `Foo* __strong`.

Currently it will give me `ambiguous specialization` if I define multiple:

```cpp
template<class U> 
struct remove_pointer<U* __weak> { .. };

template<class U> 
struct remove_pointer<U* __unsafe_unretained> { .. };

template<class U> 
struct remove_pointer<U* __strong> { .. };
```

Is there a way to remove the `ownership` OR to specialize the template to work with the different ownerships?

Comment: Just curious - is there a reason why you are defining your own `remove_pointer`, instead of using [`std::remove_pointer/_t`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/remove_pointer)?

Comment: @RemyLebeau`remove_pointer` only removes the first level of indirection. I needed to remove all levels so it becomes a class/interface.

Comment: Use smth like `template<class U> using clean_t = decltype(&*U());` to "cleanup" your pointer?

Comment: @C.M. it still fails with that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up doing:

```cpp
template<typename T>
struct is_objective_c_type {
private:
  template<class U> struct remove_pointer                    {typedef U type;};
  template<class U> struct remove_pointer<U*>                {typedef typename remove_pointer<U>::type type;};
  template<class U> struct remove_pointer<U* const>          {typedef typename remove_pointer<U>::type type;};
  template<class U> struct remove_pointer<U* volatile>       {typedef typename remove_pointer<U>::type type;};
  template<class U> struct remove_pointer<U* const volatile> {typedef typename remove_pointer<U>::type type;};
  
public:
  static const bool value = std::is_base_of<NSObject, typename remove_pointer<T>::type>::value ||
                            std::is_convertible<typename remove_pointer<T>::type, NSObject*>::value;
};
```

as it is the only thing that seems to work for `__weak`, `__strong`, `__unsafe_unretained`, etc.